# Has anyone come across issue[]?

Tags: jira-rest-api, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity, uipath-api

issue[] in UiPath. 
So I downloaded an extension / package from UiPath GO! named as "Jira Integrating Software". This Packages comes with several APIs to access Jira tickets.

I was working with one of these APIs called "Search by JQL". JQL is Jira Query Language comes in handy for Advance searching. The output type of this "Search by JQL" activity is issues[].
Now when I am Iterating this array it gives me an output of "UiPath.JiraSoftware.Models.Issue"

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **For Each** activity iterating the **ResultArray** Array you got from the Search JQL.

The following is just **pseudo** code! But it should work like this. Maybe the name of the property is not **IssueId**. That was not completely told in the document. But this you can when you inspect it by using the debug mode:
[image]

You should also have a look on the official [Jira UiPath page](https://go.uipath.com/component/jira-software-integration#resources). This resource contains all of the concepts you will need.

Comment: Hey Kwoxer, Thanks I figured out after I wrote this post.

Comment: Please always upvote or accept an answer if it's correct. This makes sure that a question is solved and others will not waste time on answering it in the future. But decide on you own. And next time do not come 2 months later ;)